# Zend Framework - Validating contents of upload (secondary validation)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm currently having users upload a MS Word Document where I am checking a version within the XML.  The controller currently checks isValid() and then hits a library that does the parsing and extraction (since word is an archive).  Now since it's technically "valid" already, I need to check the validity again through the library.  What is the best course of action in Zend Framework for this?

Cheers from Kohana Land ;)

Comment: well, I did.  Though I have the form extending zend_form with the addValidator(new My_Check);  Though, the extraction of the document takes place in the library and that happens after isValid.  In this case it would have to happen twice, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm checking actual data in the file to validate.  It needs to happen as a secondary validation.  First, all basic items are correct (its a file, less than N bytes, etc.) Then, go..ok now that that is valid..I need to do a secondary validation

Comment: Can you post the current code?  I think all you need to do is add your custom validator to the validation chain with the others (its a file, less than n bytes) but set the `breakChainOnFailure` flag to true for each of those so your special MSWord validator is only called if the other conditions are met.  This way the special validation is built into the form and there is no need to call it again after validating the form.

Comment: This framework is frustrating to me.  Coming from a framework like Kohana, this thing just seems like an OOP mess.

Just want to trigger an error after isValid, send it back to the form.  That's all.  It needs to happen after the initial isValid, if it fails, populate the form and go back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for.
You are currently calling is valid against the form, your file passes the form validation (correct size, extension ...) now you need to unpack the file and validate the contents.

I'm going to assume you already have the code to validate the contents and just want to understand how that might be used in the controller.
'

```
public function anyAction() {

$form = new Form();
//test for $_POST
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost(){
    //Test form for validity
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()){
        //will receive file upload (unless disabled in element) and filter form values,
        //based on filters attached to the elements.
        $data = $form->getValues();
        //placeholder for whatever code is required to validate contents of file
        $validateFile = new MyFileValidator();
        //test for valid file contents
        if ($validateFile->isValid($data['file']){
            //Do some Stuff 
        }
        //if file contents is not valid, display form and populate values with unfiltered values
        $form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    }
   //if form is not valid, it should stay populated and display element errors
  }
//if not post send form to view
$this->view->form = $form;
}
```

This example should provide the basic controller workflow for this type of problem. I hope it addresses your question.